# Solidity contract: How to deal with return parameters in solidity

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, tokens, exchanges

i am having an issue with an function I would like to call.

Following case:

The function looks like this:

| Params | Type |
| --- | --- |
| token0 | IERC20 |
| token1 | IERC20 |
| amount | uint256 |
| parts | uint256 |
| flags | uint256 |

and it returns

| Params | Type |
| --- | --- |
| returnAmount | uint256 |
| distribution | uint256[] |

I tried to handle the variables as following but every time I try the function, it becomes reverted. Here the line:

```
(uint returnAmount, uint[] memory distribution) = exchange.getExpectedReturn(token0, token1, amount, parts, flags);
```

Maybe someone has an idea? Do I have to define a struct to handle the params correctly? Is the function itself correct and did I make a mistake with importing the right interface?

The return I would like to handle looks like this:

```
[3400158, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Can you share the revert error?

Comment: Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Comment: You should be showing us what `getExpectedReturn` does, I don't think the problem is with the return statement. Also, consider using something like hardhat's console.log for better debugging.

Comment: I changed the Router address and was able to call the getExpectedReturn function. Netherless I get the following error message: SafeERC20: low-level call failed